# MySQL Event Scheduler not working how it should?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to set up an event/scheduler to grab the last minutes worth of data every single minute of the day with phpmyadmin.

Some how it is missing data out, it picks up some of the data but misses some out.

Can anyone advise on how to tweak my queries or another way how to do this ?

Here are the queries/events I'm using . --

**GET ALL DATA FROM TRANDATA WITHIN THIS DATE RANGE -**

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 AS SELECT ID_NO, POS, DATE,
    TIMESTAMP FROM TRANDATA WHERE DATE
    BETWEEN '2014-11-01 00:00:00' AND NOW() 
    AND POS IN ('IW1','IW2','IW3','IW4','IW5');
```

**SET EVENT TO KEEP BRINGING DATA OVER FROM TRANDATA EVERY MINUTE OF DAY**

```
CREATE event TABLE1GENERATOR ON schedule every 1 minute do INSERT INTO 
TABLE1(ID_NO,POS, DATE, TIMESTAMP) SELECT ID_NO,
POS, DATE FROM TRANDATA 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AND NOW() AND POS IN 
('IW1','IW2','IW3','IW4','IW5');
```

**CREATE SECOND TABLE AND FILTER ID_NO FOR FIRST DATE IT SEES (MIN)**

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE1FILTERED AS SELECT TABLE1.*
 FROM TABLE1
 WHERE TABLE1.DATE BETWEEN '2014-11-01 00:00:00' AND NOW() and NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT *
              FROM   TABLE1 T2_MIN               
              WHERE  T2_MIN.ID_NO=TABLE1.ID_NO
                AND T2_MIN.TIMESTAMP< TABLE1.TIMESTAMP
              );
```

**CREATE EVENT TO KEEP FILTERING DATA EVERY MINUTE -**

```
    CREATE event TABLE1FILTER ON schedule every 1 minute do INSERT INTO  
     TABLE1FILTERED (ID_NO, POS, DATE, TIME_STAMP) SELECT TABLE1.*
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE TABLE1.DATE BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AND NOW()
    and NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT *
              FROM   TABLE1 T2_MIN               
              WHERE  T2_MIN.ID_NO=TABLE1.ID_NO
                AND T2_MIN.TIMESTAMP< TABLE1.TIMESTAMP
              );
```

Comment: is this completely related to mysql ??

Comment: It's done in PHPMyAdmin so I have added that tag